# Как совершается очистка очереди от задач? / Как удалить задачу из брокера?

Tags: python, redis, celery

Я хочу автоматически очищать выполненные задачи( статус и id) из очереди. Результат задачи я очищаю автоматически прописав  `result_expires`.
Но  айди и статус все еще в брокере, как это можно очистить? Использую `redis` в качестве брокера.

Я нашел вроде бы ответ, но там нужно самому залезать в брокер и очищать руками, хотелось бы делать это через `celery`.

И буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь объяснит, как работает весь процесс очистки мусора в `celery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось куда проще:
во-первых, `pending` означает, что он не знает о задаче.
По умолчанию, задача всегда `pending` до `SUCCESS`, если не включен `task_track_started`.
Когда, воркер забирает задачу, он ее сразу удаляет из брокера(в моем случае `redis`) и хранит о ней состояние уже в backend.
Это можно просмотреть открыв `redis`:

```bash
redis-cli
keys *
LRange MyQueue 0 -1
```